# ARToolKit NFT Track Multiple Markers at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, artoolkit

Im Building an AR iOS app using **ARToolkit NFT** Feature . I have 5 NFT tackers in a printed paper . when i use the app, it only shows one Tracked object **at a time**,even other trackers are visible in the camera area. What i want is to Display **all** the virtual objects in visible trackers simultaneously ? Any fix available ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue introduced on version 5.3 where the tracker was replaced due to license issue. You can move to version 5.2.x, which uses a different tracker that does not have this bug or wait for new version to get fix.

Please Keep in mind that if you use the 5.2.x version of ARToolKit, there are licensing issues around libKPM. For more check this for more. artoolkit.org/artoolkit-licensing